# Ajax Access Php code when server some issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hello i am new in PHP i am facing problem in AJAX 
My Problem when i server issue means when wamp server not work properly and that time where i am access data use Ajax all the php code of Ajax page show on the place of data 
This problem only in Mozilla Firefox 
Check the image for more detail

```
 function completeAndRedirect()
{
   var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
   {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) 
      {
        x3 = xmlhttp.responseText;
        livemsgeload(x3);
      }
   };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "phpfiles/abnmsg.php?snd=" + str, true);
 xmlhttp.send();
}
```

[image: image of something]

Comment: That is the PHP not processing, how can that be only in FF? (Chrome and other browsers probably are auto-correcting the code) Whats the PHP?

Comment: thats problem like in feature if my server down but user want to access then they get simply my PHP code and database  password so i need solution

Comment: If the server is down nothing gets served... If you mean when the DB is down your error message outputs your password turn off display error messages.